# count sublists that has a specific term in python

Tags: python, list, sublist

I'm a newbie I want to write a function that outputs the count of sublists that contain a particular element. But my function just outputs the total count of that particular term in all the sublists.

My function:

```
def count(myList):
    tmp = []
    d = {}
    for item in myList: tmp += item
    for key in tmp: d[key] = d.get(key, 0) + 1
    return d
```

My output:

```
>>res = count_doc_frequencies([['a', 'b', 'a'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a']])
>>res['a']
4
>>res['b']
2
```

Desired output:

```
>>res = count_doc_frequencies([['a', 'b', 'a'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a']])
>>res['a']
3
```

As 'a' is present in 3 sublists..

can anyone help me modify my function to achieve the desired output ??

Comment: You don't need to write a complicated function. The `in` operator tells you if an element is present in a list or not. For example: `'a' in ['a', 'b', 'c'] == True`. So a function to check if a sublist contains an element would be: `def f(toFind, lists): return [toFind in l  for l in lists]`. And to count them, you can just do: `def f(toFind, lists): return sum([toFind in l  for l in lists])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lst = [['a', 'b', 'a'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a']]

def count(lst):
    # declare dictionary that we are going to return
    foo = {}
    # iterate sublist
    for sublist in lst:
        # make sublist into unique element list
        sublist = list(set(sublist))
        for element in sublist:
            # if element found in foo dic, increment
            if element in foo:
                foo[element] += 1
            # else, init with 1
            else:
                foo[element] = 1
    return foo

res = count(lst)
print res
```

Comment: oh now i understand . set function removes duplicates yes i got it thanks man

Comment: consider selecting the answer if I helped!

Answer (score 1):

You should change this statement

`tmp += item`

to

`tmp += set(item)`

This will eliminate the duplication count of elements in your sublists.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to write this will be

```
def count(myList,ele):
tmp = []
key = 0
for item in myList:
    if ele in item:
        key += 1
return key
```